# my animated toggle navigationbar overlaps?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I copied some code around the interwebs and came up with a navigation bar I like. The only problem is, when opening the menu the text inside overlaps weirdly. Is there a way to fix this? (watch in fullscreen)

The text is individual containers inside another container which then opens to the side. I guess that's why the text stacks.

```js
/*bar animation bar to cross*/
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
}
/*bar animation bar to cross*/
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList.toggle('open');
}
// When the user scrolls down 80px from the top of the document, resize the navbar's padding and the logo's font size
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
    document.getElementById("header").style.padding = "30px 10px";
    document.getElementById("title").style.fontSize = "40px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("header").style.padding = "80px 10px";
    document.getElementById("title").style.fontSize = "130px";
  }
}
```

```css
#header {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 50px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: 0.4s;
    position: fixed; /* Sticky/fixed navbar */
    /*outline: 5px dashed orange;*/
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 99;
}

/* Style the header links */
#header a {
    float: left;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: lato;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    /*outline: 5px dashed yellow;*/
}
#navplusicon{
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.navicon {
        margin-top: 1vw;
    /*outline: 5px dashed green;*/
    position: sticky;
}
.menu_bar_icon {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: 4px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
/* Rotate first bar */
.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-4px, 3px) ;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-4px, 3px) ;
}

/* Fade out the second bar */
.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Rotate last bar */
.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -4px) ;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -4px) ;
}
/* The side navigation menu */
.sidenav {
    float: right;
  height: 10px; /* 100% Full-height */
  width: 30px; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
  z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
  top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    overflow-y: hidden;
  padding-top: 50px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
  transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
    /*outline: 5px dashed blue;*/
}
/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    margin-top: -40px;
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #E26B00;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}

/* Style the logo link (notice that we set the same value of line-height and font-size to prevent the header to increase when the font gets bigger */
#header a#title {
  font-size: 130px;
  font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

/* Style the active/current link*/
#header a.active {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}

/* Float the link section to the right */
.navicon {
  float: right;
}

/* Add media queries for responsiveness - when the screen is 500px wide or less, stack the links on top of each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .navicon {
    float: none;
  }
}
#container{
   width: 100%;/* Your width */
   height: 100%;/* Your height */
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center; /* This will center container with items horizontally */
   align-items: center; /* This will center container with items vertically */
/*    outline: 5px dashed yellow;
*/
}

#mySidenav{
  width: 0px;
}

#mySidenav.open{
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
        <a href="#default" id="title">Kunden;</a>
            <div id="navplusicon">
              <div class="navicon">
                <div class="menu_bar_icon" onclick="myFunction(this)">
                  <div class="bar1"></div>
                  <div class="bar2"></div>
                  <div class="bar3"></div>
                  </div> 
                </div>
              <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">Über Mich</a>
                <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                <a href="#">Kontakt</a>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You alter the width of the menucontainer, so the items will try to fit and get displaced.
There are many ways to make it work, but for example you can use a fixed with and manipulate the container to overcome this issue.

```js
/*bar animation bar to cross*/
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
}
/*bar animation bar to cross*/
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList.toggle('open');
}
// When the user scrolls down 80px from the top of the document, resize the navbar's padding and the logo's font size
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
    document.getElementById("header").style.padding = "30px 10px";
    document.getElementById("title").style.fontSize = "40px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("header").style.padding = "80px 10px";
    document.getElementById("title").style.fontSize = "130px";
  }
}
```

```css
#header {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 50px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: 0.4s;
    position: fixed; /* Sticky/fixed navbar */
    /*outline: 5px dashed orange;*/
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
 z-index: 99;
}

/* Style the header links */
#header a {
    float: left;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: lato;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 4px;
 /*outline: 5px dashed yellow;*/
}
#navplusicon{
 margin-right: 30px;
}
.navicon {
  margin-top: 1vw;
 /*outline: 5px dashed green;*/
 position: sticky;
}
.menu_bar_icon {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: 4px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
/* Rotate first bar */
.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-4px, 3px) ;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-4px, 3px) ;
}

/* Fade out the second bar */
.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Rotate last bar */
.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -4px) ;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -4px) ;
}
/* The side navigation menu */
.sidenav {
 float: right;
  height: 10px; /* 100% Full-height */
  width: 30px; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
  z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
  top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
 overflow-y: hidden;
  padding-top: 50px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
  transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
 /*outline: 5px dashed blue;*/
}
/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    margin-top: -40px;
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #E26B00;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}

/* Style the logo link (notice that we set the same value of line-height and font-size to prevent the header to increase when the font gets bigger */
#header a#title {
  font-size: 130px;
  font-weight: bold;
 transition: 0.3s;
}

/* Style the active/current link*/
#header a.active {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}

/* Float the link section to the right */
.navicon {
  float: right;
}

/* Add media queries for responsiveness - when the screen is 500px wide or less, stack the links on top of each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .navicon {
    float: none;
  }
}
#container{
   width: 100%;/* Your width */
   height: 100%;/* Your height */
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center; /* This will center container with items horizontally */
   align-items: center; /* This will center container with items vertically */
/*   outline: 5px dashed yellow;
*/
}

#mySidenav{
  width: 500px;
  right:-550px;
  position:relative;
}

#mySidenav.open{
  width: 500px;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <a href="#default" id="title">Kunden;</a>
     <div id="navplusicon">
       <div class="navicon">
         <div class="menu_bar_icon" onclick="myFunction(this)">
           <div class="bar1"></div>
           <div class="bar2"></div>
           <div class="bar3"></div>
           </div> 
         </div>
       <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
         <a href="#">Home</a>
         <a href="#">Über Mich</a>
         <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
         <a href="#">Kontakt</a>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```